# sending 2 contact forms through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Webdesigner seeking deeper understanding of forms...

Hello!

I have two similar contact forms on the same page which are sent out through ajax.

Each contact form is working fine on its own, but as soon as I put them both together on the page, one of them stops working...

I know there are issues having two forms on one page, so I gave them different ids (#contactForm1, #contactForm2), which is working, but I am sure there has to be a smarter way to do this...

What advice would you give me to make this working the best way?

My html as followed:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator">
<section id="content">

  <!-- NAME -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- SUBJECT -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" required data-error="Please enter your message subject">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- MESSAGE -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea id="message" rows="7" placeholder="short description" class="form-control" required data-error="Write your message"></textarea>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <!-- EMAIL -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="email" class="email form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Adress" required data-error="Please enter your email">
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success"></i> SEND</button>
  <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
  <div class="clearfix"></div>   

</section>
</form>
```

Here my JS:

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "got everything right?");
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var msg_subject = $("#msg_subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&msg_subject=" + msg_subject + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your code does not reflect you giving your form different `id` values

Comment: because as I mentioned I thought it isnt the smartest way to do that. But you can see it as: <form role="form" id="contactForm1" ...> & <form role="form" id="contactForm2" ...> if you want...

Comment: In your AJAX call, try adding:  `async : true,`

Default is false, which means no further queries will be permitted until the first one receives a success code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `class="contactForm"` instead of `id="contactForm"` and in js:

```
(".contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {...}
```